# Why is InputStream.readObject taking so much of time reading the serialized Object

Tags: java, performance, serialization, full-text-search

Hello I am trying to implement vector space model in java. I indexed around 1000 documents using td-idf , and I use this index to search through the documents.

I figured the constructor of the class which which I used for indexing was taking too much of time ,so I decided to serialize and write the object once created to a text file say indexedFiles.txt

So now I read the text file everytime I want to search into  the collection like this

```
  fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("indexedFiles.txt");
  ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
  VSM vsm = (VSM) objectInputStream.readObject();//This statement take the most time ,
  objectInputStream.close();
```

But the readObject and casting statement takes approximately the same time as the  original constructor .

Why is this happening? ,The reason I did this was I wanted to do the indexing offline so the searching would be quick

Comment: Did you expect that deserializing the class would be faster than constructing the object in memory?  ...No.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm not certain what OP has done. I thought it was the index construction (not the object instantiation) that was the "critical path".

Comment: @ louis yes I did , is there any way I could construct the object once and store it offline and read it faster  than what I doing right now

Comment: Serialized files are binary, not text. Don't use the .txt extension for them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("indexedFiles.txt");
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
```

Try it with a `BufferedInputStream` between the `FileInputStream` and the `ObjectInputStream.` This will reduce I/O system calls by a factor of 8.

I found in practice that it lowered the time to deserialize an `ArrayList<>` with 1,000,000 items from 213s to 9s.

Comment: Deserves one thousand upvotes - thanks for the surprisingly simple solution!

Comment: Great solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Java object deserialization very resource intensive. It's often a good idea to use other serialization methods.

Java serialization is not intended for storage. Storing the index as XML would provide more abstraction for the stored data. That's another point against using Java serialization in this case.

Try using JAXB to unmarshall the object from an XML file.

Kryo serialization seems to be a very performance focused project. However, I would advice JAXB for you since I consider it to be a very reliable project. JAXB is not the most easy-to-use way out there but it's definitely worth learning.

Answer (score -1):

What has worked for me when converting a byte[] to an ObjectInputStream is the following.

```
byte[] data = ...
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
ObjectInputStream objInStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
ReceiveBuffer reBuffer = (ReceiveBuffer)objInStream.readObject();
```

This has been much faster than using a ByteArrayInputStream or a BufferedInputStream as the source for the ObjectInputStream.

Comment: You *are* using a `ByteArrayInputStream` as the source for the`ObjectInputStream`, and you haven't explained *why* it is faster than itself, or where the `byte[]` came from when you were testing with a `BufferedInputStream`, which doesn't even make sense.