# Java Socket transfer speed limit when using the internet but not when using local network

Tags: java, windows, sockets

I made a basic Java Socket to transfer files, but I noticed that when local network is used then the files are transferred at the maximum capability of the network at ~110 MB/s (on a 1 Gbps connection between the PCs), but when I switch to my internet connection then the speed is limited to around 3-3.5 MB/s. But I don't have the same limit with other applications, as I did a test with Google Drive Windows application, and with that the speed was over 40 MB/s.

This is the speed reported by Task Manager for local network test:
[Local Network speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAQiW.jpg)

This is the speed reported by Task Manager for internet test:
[Internet speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5b7P.jpg)

This is the speed reported by Task Manager for Google Driver test:
[Google Drive Speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbPVd.jpg)

Server side code:

```
ObjectInputStream dataIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
ObjectOutputStream dataOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
File file = new File(
        System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\" + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 5000000) + ".dat");
while (file.exists()) {
    file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\" + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 5000000)
            + ".dat");
}
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
Object auxKeepReading = dataIn.readObject();
if (auxKeepReading instanceof Boolean) {
    while ((boolean) auxKeepReading) {
        Object auxSize = dataIn.readObject();
        if (!(auxSize instanceof Integer)) {
            break;
        }
        Object auxBuffer = dataIn.readObject();
        if (!(auxBuffer instanceof byte[])) {
            break;
        }
        bos.write((byte[]) auxBuffer, 0, (int) auxSize);
        auxKeepReading = dataIn.readObject();
        if (!(auxKeepReading instanceof Boolean)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
bos.close();
dataIn.close();
dataOut.close();
socket.close();
```

Client side code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("IP", 40001);
ObjectOutputStream dataOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream dataIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
        new FileInputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Test.dat")));
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int sizeRead = 0;
while ((sizeRead = is.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) >= 0) {
    dataOut.writeObject(true);
    dataOut.writeObject(sizeRead);
    dataOut.writeObject(Arrays.copyOf(buffer, sizeRead));
    dataOut.flush();
    buffer = new byte[8192];
}
is.close();
dataOut.writeObject(false);
dataOut.flush();
dataIn.close();
socket.close();
```

What can cause the transfer limit considering that other applications don't have that problem, so it should not be the ISP? Also, I used `ObjectStream`, because in the application that I'm making I will be transferring other objects as well, beside that file transfer functionality.

//Edit1: I did a test using qBittorrent, were I made a torrent and tried to download it on a different PC and test this type of file transfer and I was getting similar low speeds, even a bit slower at just under 3 MB/s, which makes me now believe that there in indeed a speed limit from my ISP on some upload transfer types. I'll try contacting them.

Comment: Maybe the network is not the bottleneck. 
See BufferedInputStream trick of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506651/why-is-inputstream-readobject-taking-so-much-of-time-reading-the-serialized-obje) . Edit: ignore this. You already used it.

Comment: I think @SKi suggestion to buffer it may still make sense. You may also want to consider configuring the socket buffer size. The problem is likely that with a low latency local network, the default socket buffer is good enough for your purpose to get the data out, but with higher latency connections over the internet, the default buffer is not sufficient, meaning that there is more waiting on data, slowing down the transfer speed.

Comment: The Internet is much slower than your LAN. Don’t flush inside the loop. It destroys the whole point of buffering. And flush before close is redundant. And you don’t need a new buffer every time around the loop. And you don’t need to send the length ahead of a `byte[]` array of the correct size.

Comment: "And you don’t need a new buffer every time around the loop.": Yeah, I don't need it so I removed `buffer = new byte[8192];` and also changed the loop header to `while ((sizeRead = is.read(buffer)) >= 0)` as I don't need to control the number of bytes in this situation | "And you don’t need to send the length ahead of a byte[] array of the correct size.": This is also true, I was thinking about the situation where the array would be less then 8192, but even in that situation because of `dataOut.writeObject(Arrays.copyOf(buffer, sizeRead));` I'm only sending what was read.

Comment: But that being said, even if I remove `dataOut.flush();` from inside the loop and with the above changes, the limit is still the same unfortunately.

Comment: Well after those changes it isn't this code. You could try `new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()))` and `new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()))`, as another matter of good form.

Comment: Of course you can do this a lot faster *without* serialization, using a single connection. See my answer in [Java multiple file transfer over socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367698/java-multiple-file-transfer-over-socket).